Accessing NEON intrinsics from Go
How would one use NEON from Go? The following code
package main

// #include <arm_neon.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"

func main() {
    C.vld1q_s32(nil)
}

gives me:
➜ go build .
./main.go:9:2: could not determine kind of name for C.vld1q_s32

I'm pretty sure I have access to NEON since the following does work in C
void add(int *a, int *b, int *c, int size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i += 4) {
        int32x4_t av = vld1q_s32(&(a[i]));
        int32x4_t bv = vld1q_s32(&(b[i]));
        int32x4_t cv = vaddq_s32(av, bv);
        vst1q_s32(&(c[i]), cv);
    }
}

I'm using a M1 mac if that helps.

Might be due to the fact that vld1q_s32 is a NEON intrinsic (ARM intrinsics), which means it might be implemented as an inline function or macro and therefore not be recognized by cgo directly. Nice username btw :)

I'm pretty sure Neon intrinsics are only native to C/C++, C# and Rust for now, but you've got your workaround, that you probably should put as a solution!

I've solved it by wrapping the macro around a function and the calling the function instead of the macro.
package main

// #include <arm_neon.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
// int32x4_t _vld1q_s32(int32_t const * ptr) {
//     return vld1q_s32(ptr);
// }
import "C"

func main() {
    C._vld1q_s32(nil)
}

